# Why does `nnoremap K ko` not work on first line

Tags: key-bindings

Run `vim --clean`, `:nnoremap K ko`, and press `K` -> Nothing happens.

Run `vim --clean` and press `ko` -> Vim enters insert mode on second line.

Why?

(I know about big-`O`, this is just out of curiousity, it appeared in debugging a more complicated map)

Comment: I guess the mapping is canceled, as the `k`in the first line is an error. Depending on your settings Vim might beep or flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens, because a macro usually aborts, if not all of the typed keys work. In your case, the `k` in the first line is an error, so the macro won't try to run the `o` command.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that `k` counts as an error